# Linksys LRT224: 400 Bad Request when exporting OpenSSL client configuration file

Tags: vpn, openssl, linksys

I setup an OpenVPN client configuration on my Linksys LRT224 but when I try to  "Export Client Configuration", the browser shows a blank page with "400 Bad Request - Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request."

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to flush the Cookies of the site and log back again.